# How to copy columns from workbook to workbook without select?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to automate the conversion of one Excel-worksheet into another structure by VBA.

This is my first try with VBA and I don't find the problem at the last row of my code. How do I sufficiently declare where to copy from and where to paste?

I want to copy the entire column of the cell I found with my variables myInputBoxRange and relfind in one workbook to another empty one.

As you can see, the one workbook is opened at runtime, the other one created at runtime. Does that matter?

Are my workbooks and worksheets correctly declared for the copy to work?

I tried Range.Copy Destination := Range.
I also tried Range.Value = Range.Value

I want to set up this copy process without Select* or Activ* commands.

```
Sub firstscript()

Dim my_FileName As Variant

my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
FileFilter:="Excel Workbook,*.xlsx", _
Title:="Open EDS Copy or reported BoM")

If my_FileName <> False Then

Workbooks.Open fileName:=my_FileName

End If


Dim the_FileName As Variant

the_FileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
FileFilter:="Excel Workbook,*.xlsx", _
Title:="Name BoM-Structure and indicate file path")

If the_FileName <> False Then

Workbooks.Add.SaveAs fileName:=the_FileName

End If

Dim myName As String
    myName = Right(my_FileName, Len(my_FileName) - InStrRev(my_FileName, "\"))

Dim theName As String
    theName = Right(the_FileName, Len(the_FileName) - InStrRev(the_FileName, "\"))

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Set wb1 = Workbooks(myName)
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(1)
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks(theName)
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets(1)

ws1.ShowAllData
ws1.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

ws1.Activate

Dim myInputBoxRange As Range

On Error Resume Next

Set myInputBoxRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select header cell of reference type", Type:=8)

On Error GoTo 0

If myInputBoxRange Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "You clicked the Cancel button"

End If

Dim myIBRcol As String
myIBRcol = myInputBoxRange.Column

Dim relfind As Range
Set relfind = Range("A1:CZ2").Find("*relevance*")

Dim relcol As String
relcol = relfind.Column

ActiveSheet.Range("A2:CY2").AutoFilter Field:=relcol, Criteria1:="x"

ActiveSheet.Range("A2:CY2").AutoFilter Field:=myIBRcol, Criteria1:="<>"

'This is the row I can't solve.
ws1.Columns(ws1.myIBRcol).Copy ws2.Columns(1)


'my solution

 'Dim myIBRcol as Long, relcol as Long

 'ws1.Columns(myIBRcol).Copy Destination :=ws2.Columns(1)

End Sub
```

I either get 1004-runtime errors or Syntax errors I can't solve.

Edit: Declaring column-variables as Long instead as String solved the issue.

Comment: I think `ws1.Columns(ws1.myIBRcol).Copy ws2.Columns(1)` should be `ws1.Columns(myIBRcol).Copy ws2.Columns(1)`

Comment: Surprised it compiles at all. Typing `ws1.` would have brought up a list of all members of the `Worksheet` class/interface, and none of them go by the name of `myIBRcol`, which is a local `String` variable... the dot `.` operator stands for "dereference the object on the left and get me the member on the right". If the expression on the right of the dot isn't a member of the object on the left, expect problems.

Answer (score 1):

Copying and pasting in Excel is something I have learned explicitly from the MacroRecorder. Then, changing the code, making sure that the `workbook.worksheet.range` is always explicitly mentioned, if more than 1 workbook is involved (otherwise the workbook could be omitted). This is some minimal example, copying columns:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim workbookSource As Workbook
    Dim workbookTarget As Workbook

    Set workbookSource = ThisWorkbook
    Set workbookTarget = Workbooks.Open("SomeName")

    workbookSource.Worksheets(1).Columns(2).Copy
    workbookTarget.Worksheets(1).Columns(3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```